# ParserError: Unknown string format: "2022-11-24 04:30:14" present at position 0. Convert Pandas Column to DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have one field in a pandas DataFrame that was imported as object format. It should be a datetime variable. How do I convert it to a datetime column and then filter based on date.
It looks like this
**input:**

```
df['date_start']
```

**output:**

```
0       "2022-11-24 04:30:14"
1       "2022-11-24 15:11:51"
2       "2022-11-24 06:50:14"
3       "2022-11-24 11:27:18"
4       "2022-11-24 11:28:33"
```

I tried the following lines:

```
df['date_start'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['date_start'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'], format='%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S')
```

none of them worked

Comment: The `format` argument contains a comma that shouldn't be there.

Comment: With comma or without it still not working

Comment: The double quotes are part of the strings (I didn't see this initially), therefore `format='"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'` should do.